# How do I add data to one ruby file from another ruby file

Tags: ruby, file, edit

I have one file called `database.rb` that I want to hold a list of all the users who have input their contact information. Every time I run the file called `newuser.rb` I want to add that user to the `database.rb` file.

Here is the `new_user.rb` file:

```rb
 class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  def initialize(name, email)
    @name = name
    @email = email
  end
end

puts "What is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "What is your email?"
email = gets.chomp

user = Person.new(name, email, Time.now)
```

And the `database.rb` file would just be an empty an array that I'd like to add the new users to one by one:

```rb
[]
```

I've tried doing something like this in `new_user`:

```rb
new_user = []
new_user << user
f = File.new('database.rb', 'w')
f.write(new_user)
```

But this just replaces the current data in the `database.rb` file.

How can I keep adding to the array in `database.rb'? The list of users will end up being around 2,000 Person objects long.

Or, is this an problem where there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do and I am just thinking about the whole problem the wrong way? I'd love to hear comments on this as well.

Comment: Don't forget to indent your code especially when you're presenting it here. Proper indentation helps us understand structure and intent.

Comment: There are things to consider: How big will that list get? Do you want to add additional fields to it? Why an array in the file? I'd recommend taking a look at Sequel, which is an easy to learn but very powerful tool for talking to databases. https://sequel.jeremyevans.net. Also, you need to read about the file modes for `File.new` and how they affect files. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-new

Comment: If you wish to write the new information to the end of `database.rb` open that file for *appending* (`'a'`) rather than *writing* (`'w'`).

Comment: Saving data as Ruby code is a super bad idea. At the absolute least use a well-defined data format like JSON or YAML. Better, use something like [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) which is an actual database with far better fault-tolerance.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Appending to the .rb file won't work. Note that the file starts out with an empty array `[]`. How can you insert _into_ that array by appending to the file? I agree with tadman's suggestion to use SQLite. It may seem like a bit more work up front, but it will pay off hugely. An alternative would be to use a CSV file and keep appending to that, but that is a much worse approach than using SQLite.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, my reading was that `"database.rb"` merely contained user information, and not Ruby code, despite the `"rb"` file extension. The question is unclear.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The question explicitly states that the initial content of `database.rb` is the Ruby array `[]` and the goal is to insert elements into that array. Appending to the file won't accomplish this. And I'm sure we can agree that this would not be a good solution even if it did work. This problem would be better solved with a proper database. (And probably not SQLite, more likely something like PostgreSQL or MySQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you're mixing up data storage and retrieval. Your data can be stored in any form (plain text file, database, etc.), and your code should access the storage medium, extract the data and transform it into a form you can work with (eg. Array)

Using a database will allow you to retrieve your data a lot faster and manage it more reliably, at the cost of having to set up a database and include database functionality in your program.

Storing data on a flat file is a lot simpler, and you can open the file to view the data with any editor. This will get a lot slower as your data volume increases though. 2k records will probably take a few seconds to retrieve, as opposed to milliseconds for a database. Expect to wait minutes if your data goes up to hundreds of thousands of records.

Assuming you still want to continue using a flat file to store your data, you'll need to decide on a format to store your data in. A few of the common ones are plain text (.txt), CSV(.csv) and YAML(.yml). Using a Ruby file (.rb) to store data is not recommended as Ruby files usually store code.

Ruby comes with a couple of libraries which help you save and load data to flat files. I'd recommend you try out `YAML::Store` first. The interface is quite simple, and it gives you a nice readable YAML file. You can always convert it to something more efficient later.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html

https://redpanthers.co/pstore-ruby-standard-library/

Answer (score 2):

> Or, is this an problem where there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do and I am just thinking about the whole problem the wrong way? I'd love to hear comments on this as well.

I think that the best way to accomplish what you're looking at is using a real database, like SQLite (As suggested by @tadman). It's likely that you'll want to add more stuff beyond name and email later, plus storing thousands of different items and getting them out quickly and easily is what a database is for :)

If you learn this skill now, you can re-use it on future projects!

I just googled 'ruby sqlite tutorial' and found this one: http://zetcode.com/db/sqliteruby/connect/

Best of luck on your journey, thanks for being so open to input!